# Scripted downloading using Perl from SEC website producing encrypted documents unexpectedly

Tags: perl, encryption, web-crawler

I have a script written in Perl that retrieves "Complete submission text files" of company filings such as 8-K and 10-K statements.

Even though these files are .txt files, they are actually HTML files. Here is an example of a header of one of these particular files:

```
<SEC-DOCUMENT>0001104659-12-008133.txt : 20120209
<SEC-HEADER>0001104659-12-008133.hdr.sgml : 20120209
<ACCEPTANCE-DATETIME>20120209153739
```

This particular file is located here: https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1001838/000110465912008133/0001104659-12-008133.txt

As you can see, when you click on the file you can read the contents. However, the Perl script that downloads this file produces a file with contents that look something like this:

> ±šÜÏ¦¨^Ÿ¨T¡š¯À½ä¾‹™R¶¦
>   [T)S,”àë§–f+™•µ˜¨ÀáÊ’jv–Ié·T¡­Š¥é-“RZujKk)­š¦4¨”Þªkä‹·nðü³²¥XjSmYÎõ™?÷Úf™S[Ù}hV¢LšDÆ.zjyßý*µ“Èo¿øÒ¾²›šúOª+&ò'äòDì?Sÿyúà¹ÛùDŽ\üŸr¡ZÙÉ”òðU†þ”Š+ä
>   ¯RbZŸÎS{™òc‚ü"ð‹2@˜N”Òä'Õr¥”…_§ö€ÁV6Õín.SOsÙ|6¿MÁµì\™-•ŸqýÏ
>   ÈˆeÃ¢sSè!t/›'-)”zãöŸt¾ÞÊ–SpÃ“L¢Deòiò9ÇtúNžq˜Ø¯fÊ1òSèg—
>   6àÞ™•Hü¹¨ R‰šÕýŒÛSƒ !NdeÙ~Ü~î¹¥/EäH˜…§%«ålJ%ÒéüµÆ
>   “©Pù)á8*tÚ¡ GÕ•Ü?L?ÿ†‡ß”«@Š—X–w¶bpq§Ég{#A>JœÂ»Ól‘¼ŽH,OÆþéùðû<ù•Ìò!1*†$¾ŸúO.‘Ýÿ™¶MÙoÉ¦œýô§^²ï‰{@¼êk¦»D
>   ?}";Êl˜—¿þ˜Â~š&UøÇ³$`¬<µ¶Ò'æ¦Öž$äÔ¡×:!Âƒj$Ú:7µFèDî´®€ eŽ¿â"¿˜{«   ×fÊ©R¶H8í\WÉÃ¦¦ÖàëÜñ^Uêðž¢ÖVœ—k7zý‘j(­»øL&ª–gà³ºö›2­Ç†Ÿ¹Õ[VèVijÇXEkª&•W¨’ÞTZ«¯~z£uÕÝè–¥7c¦ÞÐêÔƒÖªë–
>   rcØ¶µÚýQC½µb-½¥ö>0´»û—ŸXzûï›öMÚJ½®µîbö-)VkQO¯ìFµ_6É¹mS1î´VŒüšüŸ!Â¦ï^Îµk¤¿”©ý\ÌÍP·J
>   ^¼ê÷Ì‹±!¿u—/´nÌöêÚ ùf}m¥
>   mY²›¤4´»V|¦Y5žîñN«HgCö1ç‚Wmã?Ñ6öýÆ¢U7/&}¢a»aöªÿÞ¨Ã=«y°æ1P^»1Ö)˜!ÕR¶’

I am wondering if this is due to encryption happening on their end. From browsing their website, it does not appear like they admit to encrypting files being transmitted over a network. I personally do not think this is the case since I can download the file fine manually within my browser.

Here is a segmenet of the Perl code that is responsible for downloading the file and saving it to the hard drive:

```
@arraydata = split(/\,/, $datagn[$j]);
if($arraydata[2] =~ m/8K/ || $arraydata[2] =~ /8\-K/){

# Starts crawler, not checking for errors
my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new( autocheck => 0 );

# Grabs address
@arraydatad = split(/\//, $arraydata[4]);

# Formats output file name
$filenamea = "Reports\\" . $dirname . "\\" . $cik . "\\" . $arraydatad[3];
chomp($filenamea);

# This is the file from the EDGAR archives
$filecrawl = "https://www.sec.gov/Archives/" . $arraydata[4];

# This crawls the file and saves it to the hard drive
$mech->get($filecrawl, ':content_file' => $filenamea);
```

The full code is here: http://pastebin.com/QXb1zcdv

Does anybody have an idea of why I am getting a file with nonsense in it when I am downloading with a Perl script from SEC.gov?

Comment: Proabably just compressed. Try removing `:content_file` and using `$response->decoded_content( charset => 'none' )` to get the file. Might be a better way.

Comment: Have you made *any* attempts to debug? Looked at a hex dump of the mystery data (far more useful than the printable view)? Used Wireshark to inspect the headers being exchanged between the client and server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`:content_file` will dump the raw content to the specific file.
If you do a `print $ua->res->headers->as_string` to get the HTTP header of the response you will see a `Content-Encoding: gzip` header. This means that is the content is compressed with gzip. A quick  `gzip -dc` on your saved file will thus provide you with the decompressed file.

As ikegami mentioned in the comment you should use `decoded_content` instead to access the data. As the name implies this will not give you the raw content but will apply the necessary decoding, in this case the decompression:

```
my $ua = WWW::Mechanize->new();
$ua->get('https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/1001838/000110465912008133/0001104659-12-008133.txt');
print $ua->res->decoded_content;
```